# Intellij idea build artifact no js and css file copied

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVt4r.png)
When I build artifact or run the tomcat in Idea,only .ftl files are copied.
The .css and .js file won't be copied.I have to copy them to the out put directory manually.

[Out put Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smn4o.png)
Anything wrong with my settings?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem.
*.js and *.css files are excluded from artifact in my **pom configuration**.
I thought pom.xml configuration is for maven build only and Idea uses its own builtin build system before.
my configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <warSourceExcludes>**/*.js,**/*.css</warSourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that your servlet-context.xml or web.xml, has as follows

```
  <!-- Additional file type mappings -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works.So Intellij Idea would copy .ftl files by default?

Comment: It uses all files in WEB-INF.

Comment: Sadly this problem has arisen again.I've add the servlet-mapping content,even the .zip file would be copied,except for .css and .js file.Maybe it's a ide bug.

Comment: Or maybe there are settings for excluding file.But I cannot find it.